# Get the tiles? (GeoWebCache, GeoServer, PostGIS, REST)

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache

I've got a PostgreSQL (9.2.9) database, PostGIS (2.1.3) enabled - and it works fine with GeoServer (2.5.2).

So by now I'm trying to make tiles of the map with the integrated GeoWebCache - but I don't get it going, because I don't know where to find the specific information for the REST service. I've read the following resources:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/geowebcache/?source=typ_redirect

http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/geowebcache/services/tms.html

http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/geowebcache/using.html

http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/services/virtual-services.html#virtual-services

But I don't see what input (URL? parameters? lat/lon bounding box? zoomfactor? scale?) is required and what I can expect to get as output (the tiles, of course, maybe some additional information).

Is there any straight example I can rely on to get a first and simple start?

Answer (score 1):

Caching is strongly related with back end configuration and front end client configuration(i.e. client's tile dimension may determine wether caching is used or not). Boundless has a great guide on caching(they use postgis, geoserver and geowebcache). I strongly recommend you to check http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/suiteintro/geowebcache/index.html .